# Generate automatic serial number of each object...In this program the constructor is used but i don't know how to do it...Can anyone do this?

Tags: c++

Create a class that includes a data member that holds a "Serial Number" for each object created from the class. That is, the first object created will be number 1, the second 2, so on.
Hints:
To do this You'll need another data member that records a count of how many objects have been created so far.(this member should apply class as a whole; not to individual objects.What keyword specifies this?) then, as each object is created, its constructor can examine this count member variable to determine the appropriate serial number for the new object.
Add a member function that permits an object to report its own serial number. then write a main() that creates three objects and queries each one about its serial number. They should respond I AM OBJECT NUMBER 2, so on.

Comment: C or C++ ? And surely a homework. What did you already try? Don't expect us to do your homework (which is expected to teach *you* something).

Comment: Hints: don't post homework to stackoverflow.

Comment: Please mark as homework, there's a tag for that.

Answer (score 3):

Please tag c++ when it's c++.

```
class blabla {
 private static int count=0;
 private int serial;
 public blabla() {
  serial=++count;
  ...
 }
}
```